# jQuery Slide in and out

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to get a div to slide down on click, which works perfectly, but when clicking the button again, i want to to be hidden, maybe with slideUp()... However im not quite sure how to do it... Any help would be appreciated...

```
var iJob = this;

this.init = function () {
    //Hook up My Page
    $("#open-mypage").one("click", iJob.onMyPageDisplayJquery);

    //Hook click event on all "mere om.."
    /*$('.more-jobs').one("click", iJob.onJobCategoryMoreInfoJquery);
    $('#more-wrapper .close').bind("click", iJob.onJobCategoryMoreHideJquery);*/

};

//Vis Min Side
this.onMyPageDisplayJquery = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //iJob.jobCategoryMoreHideJquery();

    $("#mypage-result").addClass("hidden");
    $("#mypage-li").removeClass("mypage-li").addClass("mypage-li-hover");

    $('#mypage-info').slideDown('fast', function () {
        // Load content with ajax
        return false; 
    });
};
```

As you can see, slideDown works fine, and the div is displayed - However clicking on the button again it should be hidden... I've tried this, slideToggle(), without any luck

```
//Vis Min Side
this.onMyPageDisplayJquery = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //iJob.jobCategoryMoreHideJquery();

    $("#mypage-result").addClass("hidden");
    $("#mypage-li").removeClass("mypage-li").addClass("mypage-li-hover");

    $('#mypage-info').slideToggle('fast', function () {
        ////Animation complete

    });     
};
```

Comment: Share some HTML code so we can test it, we can't just come up with a solution without knowing the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [JQueryUI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)?

I think this might do what you want already?

Comment: Not quite - i only have one button, that can open and close a div, not tabs

Comment: could you put what you currently have on jsFiddle?

Comment: ok... a little more than I was expecting. how do I get to the point where you are toggling the slide?

Comment: If you click on fx: <a href="#" id="open-mypage"><span>Min side</span></a> - it opens a div with the toggling function, when clicking the <a href="#" id="open-mypage"><span>Min side</span></a> again, i want the div to close....

Comment: And that works for you on jsfiddle too? I cannot get it to work. any chance you can clean up your html so it only includes the element you want us to test?

Answer (score 0):

`slideToggle` should work. I would suggest it's probably because you're not reversing the other actions you're taking... e.g:

```
$("#mypage-result").addClass("hidden");
$("#mypage-li").removeClass("mypage-li").addClass("mypage-li-hover");
```

Should be flipped to...

```
$("#mypage-result").removeClass("hidden");
$("#mypage-li").removeClass("mypage-li-hover").addClass("mypage-li");
```

...when clicked again.

Comment: That didn't work - Triede to delete the two lines also, but without luck

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the `one` function to bind the click handler, which will only ever fire once. Change it to use `bind`.